# Once Continuously Differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I'm hoping someone can clarify this because I can't seem to find a solid answer.

I know functions can be continuously differentiable, but I just read in a textbook *"this applies to once continuously differentiable..."* but they don't give an example and google seems unhelpful.

Am I right in assuming that once continuously differentiable is equivalent to continuously differentiable?

If not can you please provide an example that clearly demonstrates the difference.

Comment: Yes, what this is emphasising is that one needs not assume the function is twice continuously differentiable, that is there is no need to assume its derivative also has a continuous derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another simple example

$$x\mapsto \cases{0 & if $x < 0$\\x^2 & otherwise}$$

Comment: I think the discontinuity in the second derivative is clearer in this much simpler example. Clearly shows it's once continuously differentiable. Thank you =)

Comment: Yes this is simpler to see and assuming $x^n$ we can find examples for $n-1$ times continuously differentiable. You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 1):

Once continuously differentiable is indeed equivalent to continuously differentiable, but it emphasis the point that the function may not be more than once continuously differentiable. For example : 
$$x\mapsto \cases{0 & if $x = 0$\\x^3\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) & otherwise} $$
is *exactly* one time continuously differentiable.

Comment: This is due to the second derivative correct? It's undefined at x=0 and thus by having it 0 at x=0 you get the discontinuity on the second derivative?

Comment: @KennyB : if you compute the derivative of it over $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ you will have $2x\sin(1/x)-x \cos(1/x)$ which you can show it is the derivative over  $\mathbb{R}$ by taking $0$ at $x=0$, but if you derivate again, you will have terms like $\sin(1/x)$ alone and it can't be continuous at $0$.